# Why $|W_t|-L_t$ is a Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I have proved Tanaka's formula,
$$ |W_t|=|W_0|+\int_0^t \operatorname{sgn}(W_s)dW_s + L_t $$
Here $L_t$ is the local time at $0$ of the Brownian motion $W_t$.
But I don't know why it implies that $|W_t|-L_t$ is a Brownian motion a.s. I think it is because of an stochastic equations argument, but I am stuck

Comment: $ \int_{0}^{t}\operatorname{sgn}(W_{s})dW_{s}$ is a martingale with quadratic variation $t$. It's thus BM by Dubins-Schwarz theorem.

Comment: Do you know Lévy's characterization of Brownian motion (the general form of which says that a continuous local martingale $X_t$, such that $X^2_t-t$ is also a local martingale, is Brownian motion)?

Comment: I didn't knew this characterizations. Thank you all